# Can't create new Service Principals in Azure despite being under quota

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, service-principal

I can't create any new SPs in Azure despite being under quota. 
If I run:

```
 az ad sp create-for-rbac
```

I get

```
 The directory object quota limit for the Principal has been exceeded. Please ask your administrator to increase the quota limit or delete objects to reduce the used quota.
```

When I do this:

```
 az ad sp list --show-mine | grep objectId | wc -l
```

or this

```
 az ad app list --show-mine | grep displayName | wc -l
```

It shows that I don't own many applications/service principals (the default limit is 250.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out the Azure has a secret "Recycle Bin" for applications!

I did the following to empty this recycle bin

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAd -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser

Get-AzureADDeletedApplication -all 1 | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzureADdeletedApplication -ObjectId $_.ObjectId  }
```

This will permanently **remove all deleted applications** (that you owned.) If you want to be more selective then run:

```
Get-AzureADDeletedApplication -all 1
```

And go through every app deleting it like this:

```
Remove-AzureADdeletedApplication -ObjectId 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

Comment: you can do the same in UI - App registrations, Deleted Applications..

Comment: You also need to consider permissions here, you may be allowed to soft delete (put in Deleted applications, this Recycle Bin) the application but not hard delete it. Depending on your organizational setup you may need to have someone else with the right privileges do it.

So be wary, you can run yourself into hitting the quota limit without being able to revert yourself (save for soft deleting and waiting for 30 days).