# trouble deploying from azure devops because of service quota limits

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I have been battling with an issue for day now, Anytime i try to deploy from azure pipeline, i get this error:

> Failed to create an app in Azure Active Directory. Error: The directory object quota limit for the Principal has been exceeded. Please ask your administrator to increase the quota limit or delete objects to reduce the used quota.

came across a resource on stackoverflow from:
[Can't create new Service Principals in Azure despite being under quota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58935129/cant-create-new-service-principals-in-azure-despite-being-under-quota)

and followed the guide in the resource, but still didnt work.

> Get-AzureADDeletedApplication -all 1 | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzureADdeletedApplication -ObjectId $_.ObjectId  }

this is the error i get running the above command :

> Get-AzureADDeletedApplication: The term 'Get-AzureADDeletedApplication' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Please note the command was run in powershell knowing it is a powershell command. Also, if there is a cli command to use to clear this, that would be really appreciated.

I would be gad if anyone can help cause this is frustrating and i am behind time.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried in my environment and got similar error  when I run the same commands:***

```
Get-AzureADDeletedApplication
```

[image]

This error occurs due to that you have not install azureAD or install azureADPreview

1. Install the module

   install-module AzureAD or install-module AzureADPreview
2. Connect with your azure active directory by following commands with your credentials.

   Connect-AzureAD

[image]

When I connected with azure ad i can list all the ***DeletedazureADApplication.***

First I tried to delete the particular AD application it is successfully deleted.

```
Remove-AzureADdeletedApplication -ObjectId 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

[image]

Later I tried to delete all the application with following commands and got successfully deleted the azureADdeletedapplication.

```
Get-AzureADDeletedApplication -all 1 | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzureADdeletedApplication -ObjectId $_.ObjectId  }
```

[image]

***Reference:***
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaddeletedapplication?view=azureadps-2.0

Comment: Hi @Venkatesan.S-MT thanks for the write back. But i think there is a major point i didn't mention, i am running on Ubuntu. I have powershell  installed with snap , and i have followed all steps with no success. every time i try to install a module i get this "Untrusted repository" i have tried to set the repository to trusted using "Set-PSRepository" to "PSGallery" . I have also used  "Install-Module -Name Az -Repository PSGallery -Force" which ran successfully, but i still get the same error. I dont know what else to do?